# Replacing numbers in a list using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, replace

I am trying to use a dictionary to replace the last digits in a string. I extract the elements into a list, replace, and then join the list back into a string. The code runs but it only replaces using the second element in the dictionary.

```
text = "foo 123 doo 342 ghh 568 loo 243"
s = re.split(r'(\d+)', text)
textDict = {"2$":"fg" , "3$":"gh", "8$":"hj"}
for key in textDict:
    t = [re.sub(key , textDict[key], x) for x in s]
u = ["".join(t)]
u = str(u)
print u
```

I am expecting the following input

```
foo 12gh doo 34fg ghh 56hj loo 24gh
```

But am currently getting

```
foo 12gh doo 342 ghh 568 loo 24gh
```

Extending the question a little:

If I want to change *two* last digits, then I can not get neither of the solutions to work. Both of them return the original string:

```
import re

text = "foo 123 doo 342 ghh 568 loo 243"
textDict = {"23":"fg" , "43":"gh", "68":"hj"}
```

Using solution #1:

```
s = re.split(r'(\d+)', text)
for i in range(len(s) - 2):
  s[i] = s[i][:-2] + textDict[s[i][-2]] if s[i][-2] in textDict else s[i]

u = "".join(s)
print u
```

Using solution #2:

```
result_str = ''
for txt in text.split(' '):
    if txt.isdigit() is True:
        txt = txt[:-2] + textDict.get(txt[-2], txt[-2])
    result_str += (txt + ' ')

result_str.strip()
```

Comment: `$` is for end of string

Comment: What do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: You can easily fit the two solutions to your needs. If you want to generalize though, I see one problem: what if there are ambiguous keys in your dictionary? For example, if you have `{"23": "fg", "3": "fg"}`, and have the string `123`, do you want to prioritize 23 or 3?

Comment: Good point. Let's prioritize 23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution works without using `re`. I modified your `textDict`

```
In [19]: text = "foo 123 doo 342 ghh 568 loo 243"

In [20]: textDict = {"2":"fg" , "3":"gh", "8":"hj"} # modified textDict

In [21]: result_str = ''

In [22]: c_len = 1 # just modify this according to length of dict key

In [23]: for txt in text.split(' '):
    ...:     if txt.isdigit() is True:
    ...:         txt = txt[:-c_len] + textDict.get(txt[-c_len:], txt[-c_len:])
    ...:     result_str += (txt + ' ')
    ...:

In [24]: result_str.strip()    # to remove last space
Out[24]: 'foo 12gh doo 34fg ghh 56hj loo 24gh '
```

To answer you seond question, just modify `c_len` according to dict key length.

Comment: Also an interesting solution. Could you explain a little what each row of the loop does?

Comment: `text.split()` splits the text into `['foo', '123', 'doo', '342', 'ghh', '568', 'loo', '243']` then in each loop one element is picked from this splitted list. Its checkd if `txt` is a digit, if the last digit of txt is relaced by value from `textDict` dictionary. Finally value is appended to result_str with a space.

Comment: I extended the question if you want to take another stab.

Comment: Modified, I only needed to chnage txt[-c_len:] instead of txt[-1] for your second question. `c_len` is equal to length of dict keys.

Comment: OK, that makes sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @andrus Glad it helped. You can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to reverse your for loop. Instead of iterating through your keys, you can iterate through your text segments. I don't think you need to use regular expressions since you have a very specific case.

```
import re

text = "foo 123 doo 342 ghh 568 loo 243"
s = re.split(r'(\d+)', text)

textDict = {"2":"fg" , "3":"gh", "8":"hj"}
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
  s[i] = s[i][:-1] + textDict[s[i][-1]] if str(s[i][-1]) in textDict else s[i]

u = "".join(s)
u = str(u)
print u
```

This gives the following output :

```
> foo 12gh doo 34fg ghh 56hj loo 24gh
```

I believe this is also more efficient since instead of having two nested loops (which gives us a complexity in the order of `O(n*m)`), you iterate through one list, which gives us `O(n)`.

Comment: I extended the question if you want to take another stab.